# Functions.php change for Woocommerce not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, actions

I am trying to add this to functions.php. In my test lab on a different site it adds the test info information fine. But on the website I am trying to add it to nothing happens. The website is running a builder thrifty theme with the latest woocommerce. Any ideas? I'm basically just wanting to add a line of text on every product page that is like a disclaimer but can't.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','print_something_below_short_description');

function print_something_below_short_description() {
    echo 'Test Info.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the theme or another plugin are using that hook with a later priority. Your `add_action` would have the default of 10; try giving it a 12 or a 20, etc. and see if the text shows up.

`add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','print_something_below_short_description', 10);`

You can [read about Priority with Action Hooks here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. Hope it will work now.

```
function action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form(  ) { 
    echo 'Test Info.';
};        
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 10, 0 );
```